# public static или static public

Tags: php

Приветствую, коллеги.

Собственно, интересует, в чем же принципиальная разница между объявлением метода в классе... Кроме общепринятых стандартов, есть ли разница в использовании этих двух методов класса?

```
class A {
   public static function MethodOne() {
       //return;
   }
   static public function MethodTwo() {
       //return;
   }
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: ну в одном случае у вас публичный статический метод, а в другом статический публичный метод... шутка, я думаю разницы нет, но правильно писать `public static`

Comment: иррелевантно, амбивалентно, однохерственно

Comment: Нагуглил много всего, и могу сам ответить на свой вопрос. Согласно стандарту PSR-2, static должен быть объявлен после объявления модификатора области видимости public :)

Comment: @AndrewKoshkin напишите тогда свой ответ. А то зашел с ссылкой на PSR, а тут уже все известно :)

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ:

Согласно регламенту [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

> Visibility MUST be declared on all properties and methods; abstract and final MUST be declared before the visibility; **static MUST be declared after the visibility**.

Стало быть, *static public* и *public static* идентичны, но верным решением согласно стандартам написания кода является public static